# Change price field according to exchange rate django

Tags: python, django, currency-exchange-rates

is there anyway to change price field dynamically according to the days exchange rate of dollar? in django??
Example:

```
class Sales(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField()
""" other codes goes in here """
```

Comment: It might be better to use `django-money`: it allows to use different currencies, as well as exchange rates https://github.com/django-money/django-money

Comment: ooh let me have a look at it then

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem solved the problem precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a simple api to look up the exchange rate, for example, this one gives the exchange rates every 30 minutes (no registration needed).

http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=EUR_USD&compact=y

It would be dynamically, and no a fixed price rate conversion.

i know there are some limitations, but it could work if you're on a small project, otherwise, you would scrape some data from other pages using beautiful soup.